# Why do I not get same fuzzy match results when I flip strings in pattern and x in R's agrep?

Tags: r, agrep

So the following command gives me a match:

`agrep(pattern = 'Ned Stark', x = 'Ned Stark**DUPL ENTRY', max.distance = 0.15, costs = NULL, ignore.case = TRUE, value = FALSE, fixed = TRUE, useBytes = FALSE)`

But when I flip the two strings, then I no longer get a match

`agrep(pattern = 'Ned Stark**DUPL ENTRY', x = 'Ned Stark', max.distance = 0.15, costs = NULL, ignore.case = TRUE, value = FALSE, fixed = TRUE, useBytes = FALSE)`

Comment: The pattern is searched for *within* the string.  In the first instance there is match within the set distance parameter.  In the second, there isn't.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it matches in both cases without changing max.distance?

Comment: No, the only way to get a match in the second case is to increase the max distance. Perhaps if you step back and explain what you're trying to achieve there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: I need to detect duplicate (not exact) entries in the table. So in this case 'Ned Stark' is the same as 'Ned Stark**DUPL ENTRY', but whichever I use as 'source' and other as 'target', I need to get consistent matching results based on distance parameter in both cases. Do you think other algorithm or function is more appropriate then?